# Possibility to allow long initialization of the instance in GAE?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gmail-api

I'm writing a software that will automatically process messages from the user's gmail inbox (business inbox in our domain). The intention is to deploy this software to Google App Engine and I can't get my head around the following scenario:

Upon the start of the software I'd like it to process the messages that accumulated from before the automation was started. As I expect hundreds of messages in the inbox, this phase might take some time. I was looking into the following options:

1. The synchronous way: Start a separate long-running thread to process the pending messages synchronously and use the main thread to put notifications about new incoming messages into a separate queue that will be processed later.
   Result: the thread responsible for processing the pending messages is killed as soon as the main thread is through the rest of the code. This is sort-of expected now after reading [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/runtime#threads):

   > Note that threads will be joined by the runtime when the request ends so the threads cannot run past the end of the request.
2. The asynchronous way: Use the batch calls for getting the messages and process the results by a callback. Result: every-time the result was expected the instance has been restarted and context lost.

   ```
   from apiclient.http import BatchHttpRequest

   batch = self.service.new_batch_http_request(callback=self.cbk_request_messages)
   batch.add(self.service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=id, format='metadata'))
   batch.execute()
   ```

Or am I using GAE in a completely wrong way here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's true, you lose the context of the original request, but nothing stops you from extracting the needed info from that context and pass it to subsequent requests so that they can re-create that context. Of course, you'll have to persist only the relevant info from the original instance/request context, not the ephemeral context itself.

For example, let's say that the original request is the one displaying the homepage for the user after login, when there's a ton of new emails that need processing. You won't be able to process those messages fast enough to immediately display in that page that the emails were processed. But you can get the mailbox information and enqueue a mailbox processing task in a push queue with that mailbox info as a parameter.

The task gets the mailbox info, processes a batch of emails from that mailbox and, if there still are emails to be processed, enqueues another such task, propagating the mailbox info to it. These tasks keep running until there are no more emails to be processed.

You can even have the homepage issue repeated AJAX requests in the background to obtain the status of the email processing tasks and maybe display some progress information like X emails yet to be processed, if you want.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Dan. I think I haven't described the second scenario well - if I issue a batch request from the front-end as decribed, the callback method is never called and the instance is restarted instead of the callback method execution. I'm unable to retrieve the results of my operation this way.

Comment: You can't use that method, as it needs the original request context. You do it the syncronous way, but from inside the push task handler.

Comment: Thank you, in the meantime I came to the very same approach and I can confirm it works this way.